# HTML Mail Cursor Pointer Hack On Gmail

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

According to [This List](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) Gmail is not supporting the cursor properties

[image]

now my question is if any body knows any hack to use in sending newsletters or HTML Mails with Cursor Pointer enable in Gmail?

Thanks